# How to plot decision boundary with multiple features in octave?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, octave, logistic-regression

I'm coding a logistic regression model in and I'm trying to plot a decision boundary but its showing a wrong representation, I couldn't find what's wrong. I have 9 features to represent.

```
function plotDesicionBondary(theta, X, Y)
% Plot Data
plotData(X(:,2:3), Y);
hold on

if size(X, 2) <= 3
    % Only need 2 points to define a line, so choose two endpoints
    plot_x = [min(X(:,2))-2,  max(X(:,2))+2];

    % Calculate the decision boundary line
    plot_y = (-1./theta(3)).*(theta(2).*plot_x + theta(1));

    % Plot, and adjust axes for better viewing
    plot(plot_x, plot_y)

    % Legend, specific for the exercise
    legend('Admitted', 'Not admitted', 'Decision Boundary')
    axis([30, 100, 30, 100])
else
    % Here is the grid range
    u = linspace(0, 10);
    o = linspace(0, 10);

    z = zeros(length(u), length(o));
    % Evaluate z = theta*x over the grid
    for i = 1:length(u)
        for j = 1:length(o)
            z(i,j) = mapFeature(u(i), o(j))*theta;
        end
    end
    z = z'; % important to transpose z before calling contour

    % Plot z = 0
    % Notice you need to specify the range [0, 0]
    contour(u, o, z, [0, 0], 'LineWidth', 2)
end
hold off

end
```

and here's the function mapFeature

```
function out = mapFeature(X1, X2)
degree = 3;
out = ones(size(X1(:,1)));
for i = 1:degree
    for j = 0:i
        out(:, end+1) = (X1.^(i-j)).*(X2.^j);
    end
end

end
```

here's the figure 
[image: Here's the representation]

What should I change ?

Comment: It looks like you will need a neural network for linearly non-separable data.
Basically you want to draw a line, that separates all yellow points from black ones?

Comment: I don't expect you'll be able to plot 9-dimensional space on a 2-dimensional display. You may need to find another way to visualize your results.